# What are basic requirement of SharePoint Migration 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, sharepoint-on-prem, 2016

I am currently on SharePoint 2007 and would like to know the recommended upgrade path and technique from 2007 to 2016?

Comment: You need to make this question more specific. What exactly are you looking for information about?

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft says](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30371)

> The database-attach method is the only supported method for upgrading

And your upgrading path should be

1. 2007 to 2010
2. 2010 to 2013
3. 2013 to 2016

I have a article on 2010 to 2013. Same thing works for 2013 to 2016.

[SharePoint Migration 2010 to 2013](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1105686/SharePoint-Migration-to)

Answer (score 1):

I think in your situation migrating from 2007 to 2016, you have following options.

1. Use the 3 red party tool I.e sharegate or metalogix... (They offer free trial as well). This will help you error free migration, also reduced the cost in term of setting up too much sp farm(2010,2013,210)
2. Another Option, if you don't have too much customization, only content then migrate the content manually.
3. As there is no direct upgrade path from 2007 to 2016. You need 2010,2013 farms for short time. As you 1st need to upgrade 2010 then 2013 and finally to 2016. I won't recommend this approach as margin of error is high

Answer (score 0):

In my experience database-attach method works best for the upgrade path from 2007 > 2010 > 2013 > 2016. The level of customization is a big factor though.